# No asigna el valor a la direccion de memoria apuntada

Tags: c, punteros

Tengo la funcion main que tiene declarada un array int de 4 posiciones e intento llamar a una funcion que recibe un numero(var1) y el array int, dependiento el valor que llegue de var1 , va a incrementar en 1 lo que tenga el array int, dentro de la funcion el valor se incrementa, pero cuando vuelvo a main se ve en 0

```
  int main(){
      ...
      int cantPlayer[4];
      int typePlayer; 
      setPlayer(typePlayer, cantPlayer);
    }
    
    
    int countPlayerPerType(int *typePlayer, int *cantPlayer) {
        switch ((int)typePlayer) {
        case 1:
            cantPlayer[0] = cantPlayer[0] + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El primer parámetro de la función es de tipo `int*` y tu estás pasando `typePlayer` que es `int`.

Si solo quieres el valor de la variable, cámbiale el tipo a `int`:

```
int countPlayerPerType(int typePlayer, int *cantPlayer) {
     ...
}
```

Si quieres un puntero, deja la función como esta y al llamar la función pasa la dirección de memoria de `typePlayer` con el operador [`&`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access#Address_of):

```
setPlayer(&typePlayer, cantPlayer);
```